# How to iterate through all Groups, TermSets, Terms and all Sub Terms

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata, groups, term, term-set

I want to copy the exact hierarchy (as seen below) of Groups, termsets and all level of terms from one MMS to another MMS:

[image]

I am looking for sample server side API code to perform this from where i can get an idea?

I have used following command to export whole the termstore:

```
Export-SPTerms -TermStore (Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $sourceMMSWebApp).TermStores[0] -OutputFile "c:\temp\termStore.xml"
```

now, i want to import all the groups to destination MMS, which command should i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Script Created by http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/downloads/

There is a cmdlet that allows to export terms into an XML file and another cmdlet that allows importing from xml file.

http://www.falchionconsulting.com/PowerShellViewer/Default.aspx?Version=SP2010&Cmdlet=Export-SPTerms

http://www.falchionconsulting.com/PowerShellViewer/Default.aspx?Version=SP2010&Cmdlet=Import-SPTerms

Comment: I don't know who down voted. If you read the question. OP is asking how to move term from one MMS to Another.

Comment: thanks for this useful info: I have updated question, can you please look into that?

Comment: Use the second link..http://www.falchionconsulting.com/PowerShellViewer/Default.aspx?Version=SP2010&Cmdlet=Import-SPTerms

Comment: thanks! i am exporting group one by one, but i am getting this error: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: lcid, how i fix this

Comment: @SPBeginer it seems your error contains `<` - better update it in question.